# Group-by operation for another column R

Tags: r, group-by, multiple-columns

I'm looking to perform operations for one column based on grouping for another column.

Say I have the following data:

```
user <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
score <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
time_1 <- c(130, NA, 120, 245, NA, NA, NA, 841, NA, NA, 721, 612)
time_2 <- c(NA, 742, NA, NA, 812, 212, 214, NA, 919, 528, NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(user, score, time_1, time_2)
```

We get the following df:

```
   user score time_1 time_2
    1     1    130     NA
    1     0     NA    742
    1     1    120     NA
    1     1    245     NA
    2     0     NA    812
    2     0     NA    212
    2     0     NA    214
    2     1    841     NA
    3     0     NA    919
    3     0     NA    528
    3     1    721     NA
    3     1    612     NA
```

For every user 1, what is the smallest value of `time_1`?
So I am looking to group users by their number, and perform an operation on column `time_1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update on OP request(see comments):
Just replace `summarise` with `mutate`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  mutate(Smallest_time1 = min(time_1, na.rm=TRUE))

    user score time_1 time_2 Smallest_time1
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>
 1     1     1    130     NA            120
 2     1     0     NA    742            120
 3     1     1    120     NA            120
 4     1     1    245     NA            120
 5     2     0     NA    812            841
 6     2     0     NA    212            841
 7     2     0     NA    214            841
 8     2     1    841     NA            841
 9     3     0     NA    919            612
10     3     0     NA    528            612
11     3     1    721     NA            612
12     3     1    612     NA            612
```

We could use `min()` inside `summarise` with `na.rm=TRUE` argument:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  summarise(Smallest_time1 = min(time_1, na.rm= TRUE))
```

```
 user Smallest_time1
  <dbl>          <dbl>
1     1            120
2     2            841
3     3            612
```

Comment: That works great. Is it possible to assign the values of `Smallest_time1` to the user in the original df in a new column?

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: Similarly, is it possible to compute this operation only when say `score = 1`?
Edit: I used the filter() and worked well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could use `ifelse` like: `df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  mutate(Smallest_time1 = ifelse(score==1, min(time_1, na.rm=TRUE), time_1))`